# excel named ranges in VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I am using

```
Worksheets("Named_ranges").Range("A1").ListNames
```

to write the list of named ranges in the `Named_ranges` sheet but the result is like

```
is_pp4 = Checklist!$D$28
```

so to show the contents of `=Checklist!$D$28`, I need to press F2 and then Enter. I have tried to search and replace the = with = as suggested on other answers and it works when executed from Excel interface but it has to be done automatically with VBA script and from there the search and replace method does not solve the problem. The Calculations options are set to Automatic.

Comment: Could you please provide any code of what you've done so far - espacially the part were you write the information to the cell.

Comment: The whole vba code is `Sub named_ranges()
Worksheets("Named_ranges").Range("A1").ListNames
End Sub` this takes the named ranges from the whole workbook and enters the name in A column of sheet Named_Ranges and the value in column B

Comment: Sorry overread that line - Rorys solution should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you describe:

```
With Worksheets("Named_ranges").Range("A1")
    .ListNames
    .CurrentRegion.Numberformat = "General"
    .CurrentRegion.Replace "=", "=", xlPart
End With
```

Edit: I think there may be a timing issue with `ListNames` so it may be better to loop:

```
Dim n As Long
Dim arrData()
With ActiveWorkbook.Names
ReDim arrData(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
For n = 1 To .Count
    arrData(n, 1) = .Item(n).Name
    arrData(n, 2) = .Item(n).RefersTo
Next n
End With
Worksheets("Named_ranges").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), 2).Value = arrData
```

Comment: The code is working and replacement is done but the result is still like is_pp4 = Checklist!$D$28 and i have to press f2 and enter to get the contents.

Comment: It worked for me but perhaps you have formatted the cells as Text so try the revised version.

Comment: Now i have tested your code it works with a simple test file with only one named range but does not work in a huge 22 worksheet file with about 150 named  ranges (with goal of 7000 named ranges) majority of which refer to other cells and formulas. The  search and replace from the excel interface is working though

Comment: I've added an alternative version.

Comment: the alternative version is working thank you very much!